# NodeJs Generating a Sudoku Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, sudoku

I want to generate a sudoku puzzle using nodejs and recursion.

The state of my program is as follows

I start with an array of 81 zeros.

Next, I fill the 1st, 4th, and last block with nine different numbers from 1-9 because I can generate these numbers without worrying about blocks, rows, or columns.

The next step is the part I am stuck on, which is solving the actual sudoku.

I have created a "getSudokuNumbers" function which returns all of the numbers in the block, row, and column for a given cell.

Then I check if there is a number in that cell that is a possible solution

However, when the program is run there is sometimes an issue where there is no valid solution.

Essentially, my program doesn't try every solution to the puzzle, which is what I need it to do...

You can check out my codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-ishizaka-cn6g3?file=/src/index.js

Below highlights the important parts of the program

```js
sudokuArr = new Array(81).fill(0);

// fills the first, fourth, and last block with numbers from 1-9
fillGrid()

const solveGrid = () => {
  // loop over every cell in the sudokuArr
  for (let i = 0; i < sudokuArr.length; i++) {
    // gets the index of the cell's block, row, and col
    const { block, row, col } = getSudokuVars(i);

    // gets the numbers in the current cell's row, column, and block
    const blockNums = getNumbersInBlock(block),
      rowNums = getNumbersInRow(row),
      colNums = getNumbersInCol(col);

    // all the numbers to try for every cell
    const numsToTry = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    numsToTry.forEach((num) => {
      // check that the number is a valid sudoku number
      // however, this is where the problem arrises because sometimes the blockNums, colNums, and rowNums include every number from 1-9 and the program does not do anything.
      // I believe this is where I need some sort of recursion/brute force algorithmn to 
      // try ever possible solution
      if (
        !blockNums.includes(num) &&
        !rowNums.includes(num) &&
        !colNums.includes(num)
      )
        return (sudokuArr[i] = num);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Lots of missing code here: `getSudokuVars`, `getNumbersInBlock`, `getNumbersInRow`, `fillGrid` etc. The design looks brittle, `fillGrid()` appears to mutate a global. Better to use parameters and return values and keep functions 100% locally scoped instead of tied to globals. Also, I'm not sure why you need to solve it if you're trying to generate an (unsolved?) puzzle. What is the expected output, exactly? Please see [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: I have a link to my codepen which has all the code... I know that using globals isn't necessarily "good" but right now I'm focusing on making the algorithmn itself work not javascript best practices... The codepen shows how right now the code isn't working as I expect. What I expect is to create an array of 81 numbers that generate a valid sudoku. I want to use it in this app https://natejsimonsen.github.io/sudoku-app/. Right now I have a working sudoku generator but it is really slow and if this new one I'm working on works it will be much quicker.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding external codepen/sandbox, In the link I shared, it says "…Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem _in the question itself_" (emphasis theirs). SO offers [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that run JS. So the 81 numbers is a valid solved sudoku? It seems you can simply run any solver algo on an empty board then, if I'm not mistaken? The issue is speed, not correctness, at this point?

Comment: At this point the problem is correctness, the sudoku generates some of the numbers correctly, but as you can see some of the numbers are 0 which means that there is no valid number to use....